# Packaged mozzarella wet

Tags: food-safety, cheese

I bought some mozzarella sealed in plastic and noticed that there is a bit of liquid in the package with a few tiny bubbles. Is this normal? And safe to eat? It's not bulging at all. It has 48% moisture I think and is low fat. Maybe this is more traditional mozzarella?

Comment: Is it fresh mozzarella?  that often has some whey in the package, if the liquid is the only concern... though of course it will depend on type of mozz, and storage conditions, and other factors to tell whether it's safe or not.

Comment: In the UK mozzarella is always sold in liquid, this sounds normal to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's 2 types of mozzarella, fresh and hard (also called low moisture). Fresh mozzarella is soft and packaged with whey or brine, it tears easily and can be squished between your fingers. It has a relatively short shelf life, usually within a couple of weeks of purchase. If you have this cheese then this sounds normal to me, even a couple of bubbles, if it smells fine and tastes fine I'd think it's safe to eat.

Hard mozzarella has been allowed to dry partially, and is generally sold in vacuum packaged blocks, with no liquid. It's very firm and shred-able with a grater. If you've bought this and you have liquid and bubbles in the package then I would get rid of it.

Comment: This is potentially anecdotal, but it's often easy to tell what you've got just based on shape. Fresh mozzarella tends to come in rounded balls; hard or skimmed mozzarella is cut into cubes or bricks, like cheddar or other firm cheeses.

Comment: @logophobe I think mine is somewhere in between. It's sort of a block, sort of rounded. The package is not bloated at all.